# How to define where to display database values?

Tags: php, html

I need to know how can I define where the values from the database get displayed. I have a HTML form and the data gets to the database and it gets out also but not in the places that it should be.

This is my HTML:

```
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <form method="post" action="post/insert_ac.php"> 
   <td>
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox">

   </td>
  <td>
 <div class="hidden">
  <p>
   <label for="another-simple-input" style="font-size:14px;">Date:</label>
    <input type="text"  class="round default-width-input" id="datetimepicker1" style="width:80px;" name="Date"/>                        
  </p>
 </div>
  </td>
  </form>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

And this is my database request PHP:

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="myuser_name"; // Mysql username 
$password="PASSWORD"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="mydata_base"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="table"; // Table name 

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "myuser_name", "PASSWORD")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db('mydata_base', $link) or die("cannot select DB");

$query = "SELECT `Date` FROM `table` WHERE 1";

$table = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($table, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$Date = $row['Date'];

 echo "  
<div style='margin:30px 0px;'>
   Date: $Date<br />
</div>
";
 }


?>
```

I want the `$Date` to be displayed in the HTML `<input type="text"  class="round default-width-input" id="datetimepicker1" style="width:80px;" name="Date"/>`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 2 options from your last comment:

1) include the php file in your html file:

```
<?php
    include("phpfilename.php");
?>
```

and then you can use the variable wherever you want.

2) redirect the php file to your html and pass the variable:

```
<?php 
   header('location: htmlfilename.php?date='.$date); exit(0); 
?>
```

then in the html file you can get the date from the URL. Ideally this file is also .php so you can use:

```
<input type="text" class="round default-width-input" id="datetimepicker1" style="width:80px;" name="Date" value="<?php echo $_GET["datum"]; ?>" />
```

Comment: Where do i need to add the `$_GET["$date"]` and how?
I got this now:
PHP
`<?php
  ...
echo header('location: mydocument.html?date='.$date); exit(0);
   }
   ?>`
And the HTML: 
    `<input type="text"  class="round default-width-input" id="datetimepicker1" style="width:80px;" name="Date" value=""' $_GET["$date"]' >/>`   

The value method dosen't work.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Make sure that the html file is also .php

Comment: Okey, just figured out that this method will not work for me, since i have about 40 inputs and 20 textareas.
How does the include method work?
So i have included the phpfile to my HTML file.

Comment: you still need to name your html file .php and then you can call your variables using `<?php echo $datum; ?>` (refer to my first answer)

Comment: The first answer will be do good. But when i make `echo $date. $weather. $time`
then everytginh appears in the first input and also in the others but all mixed up and together. How can i separate them and place them spretley in the input field's?

Comment: The `.` (dot) is used to concatenate.  To display separately, change this accordingly `<?php echo $datum; ?>` and `<?php echo $weather; ?>` etc.. and you can put them anywhere you want in your code.

Comment: So then i need to make alot of .php files that will get the data from the database, right?
Will this effect the website?

Comment: you can have one .php file if you want - depends on how you are constructing the website. Each form can have it's own php file. In any case this will not affect the performance.

Comment: so how would my echo look like in the .php file if i wanted to have all the $ in one php and sort them in the html?

Comment: It really depends on what you intend to implement.. in principle php is easy - you assign the data/content in a $variable and then use echo to display that $variable. At this I suggest you learn some basic php (google can help a lot).  Your question has been answered successfully (if so please mark as answered). If you need more help, I suggest you raise another question but please do some php reading before.

Comment: Micallef, thank you very much!
You have helped me alot. :)
Tnx again.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<input type="text" class="round default-width-input" id="datetimepicker1" style="width:80px;" name="Date" value=<?php echo $Date; ?> />
```

Comment: This is just giving me from start on, a input of <?php echo $datum; ?>.
So this will not do the trick, Thank's anyway.

Comment: do you want it displayed as a label or in the input? You can place this tag wherever you wish to display the `$Date` - `<?php echo $Date; ?>`. On a side note I would avoid using $Date as a variable as `date()` is a php function.

Comment: Emm i want it to be an input also in the input window.
But if i use `value"<?php echo $dDate; ?>"`
Then exactly `<?php echo $dDate; ?>` is displeyd in the input and not the the value from the database.
P.s. i am not actully using `$date` i just wrote that coz in my language no one would understand what my value should be. :)
Do you got maybe any other advice regarding this problem?

Comment: Why don't you use different variables for your form and from your database?

Comment: And what would that bring? I don't understand, sorry.
I want to displey the results on the same page as i can enter the values.

Comment: I fail to understand what you want to achieve. Where exactly do you wish to display the date coming from the database?

Comment: I want the data to get to the html page.
Okey i will try to explaine i have to seperate doucuments one HTML and one PHP. The HTML document is the main document and there i handle the from. I want the PHP to get the values and place them into the HTML page where i need tem. 
I hope i was more precise. :)